# How to retrieve column names from a table of object custom type

Tags: plsql

Looking to find out how to get the columns of the objects comprised in a table defined in a custom type (introspection). For instance, having the following type object specification

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ITEM_OBJ AS OBJECT ( 
  -- 
  name VARCHAR2(25),
  type VRCHAR2(6),
  -- 
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION ITEM_OBJ ( 
    -- 
    name VARCHAR2, 
    type VARCHAR2
    -- 
  ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT 
-- 
);
```

and a table of said objects,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ITEM_TBL AS TABLE OF ITEM_OBJ
```

how do we retrieve a collection of the original object fields out of a locally defined variable within an anonymous block? In this case, an array `['name', 'type']`.

```
DECLARE
    L_items_tbl ITEM_TBL;
BEGIN
    -- L_items_tbl contains the result set
    ITEMS_PACKAGE.RETRIEVE_ITEMS(O_items_tbl => L_items_tbl);

    -- goal here is to get the array ['name', 'type']
END;
```

Comment: Presumably you'll want to get the names and values of each element in the collection, not just one name/type pair. I'm afraid there's nothing generic built-in for this though. Your best bet might be to give the type a method for this, so that you can call it for each l_items_tbl(n).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson yes, the goal would be to be able to iterate over all object fields. you're suggesting something like hardcoding the fields, right? that would be far from ideal. thing is, I have reasons to believe what I am trying to do is possible since Oracle REST Data Services does something similar with their collection queries. they are able to parse a table of objects into a JSON whose keys match the object fields.